# How to get the label for DateField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How to display the label for the field DateField?

My model has the following field:

```
drum_period_1 = models.DateField(
    'qwerty',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
)
```

forms.py:

```
class DrumDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    drum_period_1 = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'datepicker',
        }),
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'drum_period_1', 
        )
```

template.html:

```
<label class="label">{{ form.drum_period_1.label }}</label>
```

The displayed label is 'drum_period_1', but 'qwerty' had to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label):

> The default label for a Field is generated from the field name by
>   converting all underscores to spaces and upper-casing the first
>   letter. Specify label if that default behavior doesn’t result in an
>   adequate label.

Pass the `label` argument to the `DateField` constructor:

```
drum_period_1 = forms.DateField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'datepicker',
    }),
    required=False,
    label = "qwerty"
)
```

Or, rename `drum_period_1` to `qwerty`:

```
class DrumDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    qwerty = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'datepicker',
        }),
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'qwerty', 
        )
```