# How do we add a label to a Django models.dateTimeField?

Tags: django, django-models

We are trying to assign a more sensible label with an input date in our Django admin's console. Code in the models file:

```py
bacteria_time = = models.DateTimeField(datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("America/New_York")), null=True, blank=True)
```

In the changelist to the left of the date created we see a long date string. We would like to either format it with a label, or name, or something that relates it as the "Bacteria Sample Time" instead of the date on the laft and the date in the box. I'm sure we are just haven't the page of proper documentation.

Comment: Pass the label argument to the DateField constructor. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547358/how-to-get-the-label-for-datefield).

Comment: Looks like this answers your question: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#label

Comment: Are DateField and DateTimeField used the same way?  I'm not sure they are.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `get_form()` method that may be overridden in admin.py for creating custom forms. Within this function we can call out labels like this:

```py
form.base_fields["bacteria_time"].label = "Time Sample was Taken"
```

And in whichever `@admin.register(MyAdmin)` create the form object:

```py
form = EquipServiceAdminForm
```

create a CustomAdminForm with that particular field listed. In my case I was simply using all of them like so:

```py
class Meta:
        model = EquipService
        fields = "__all__"
```

More inför can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/)